# How to call other HTTP based microservices in GoLang with Go-Kit

Tags: go, microservices

So, I have two microservice that are HTTP-based. I want to call the other service is there is any `Go-Kit` way to call other microservices? Or just the old way?

I'm doing this right now, which feels kinda wrong.

```
postBody, _ := json.Marshal(map[string]string{
   "name":  "Toby",
   "email": "Toby@example.com",
})
responseBody := bytes.NewBuffer(postBody)
resp, err := http.Post("http://localhost:8080/", "application/json", responseBody)
if err != nil {
   log.Fatalf("An Error Occured %v", err)
}
```

Comment: What about this feels wrong? Are you asking if gokit has its own http client?

Comment: @OneCricketeer yeah kinda or should I use reverse proxy?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with this code. Stdlib functions should be preferred. Reverse proxies won't solve anything here as you still need a client to communicate with some endpoint

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thank you for taking your time to comment. One more question. Can I do a fire and forget kinda request with this code as well?

Comment: HTTP, by definition, is not fire and forget. You might also want to look at the http example here https://gokit.io/examples/stringsvc.html

Comment: @OneCricketeer okay! Thank you, man! Appreciate it!